# И еще о ряхах и неряхах

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Во-первых, большое спасибо за ответ по "неряхе".
Во-вторых, в ответе был такой текст: "Преф. производное от *ряха* «опрятно одетая»". И стало интересно: грубо-простонародное "ряха", то есть, "толстая морда", родственно вышеупомянутой ряхе или нет? А еще есть напиток "ряженка" (или это совсем уже не в тему?)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И стало интересно:
> грубо-простонародное "ряха", то есть,
> "толстая морда", родственно
> вышеупомянутой ряхе или нет?

Родственно *лохани* и *помойному ведру.* См.:

**РЯХА**, -и, **РЯШКА**, -и, ж, **РЯШНИК**, -а, м. Лицо, морда (обычно толстая); толстый, сытый, объевшийся человек. *Ряху наесть.*
Ср. *устар. диал.* «ряшка», «ряжка» — лохань, помойница, банная шайка, ведро, черпак.

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_12099

> А еще есть напиток "ряженка" (или это
> совсем уже не в тему?)))

Ни с *ряхой*, ни с *неряхой* связи, скорее всего, нет. См. http://www.verling.ru/books/tfpukhova-folklor-i-literatura:-problemy-izucheniya-razdel-2/stranica-7 :

> Этимология слова ряженка затемнена;
> можно привести несколько версий
> относительно происхождения данной
> лексемы. Согласно одной из них
> (Ж.Ж.Варбот), это слово заимствовано
> из украинского языка, где оно является
> литературным; например, в
> «Украинско-российском сло­варе»
> (главные редакторы Л.С.Паламарчук,
> Л.Г.Скрипник) (УРС) нахо­дим: «Ряжанка
> - варенец, обл. ряженка» (с.737). В русский язык оно пришло через диалекты
> - в пользу этого свидетельствует и то, что оно бытует в русских говорах, и
> то, что первоначально в
> лексикографиче­ских источниках оно
> имело помету «областное». В связи с
> этим можно утверждать, что слово это
> имеет отвербальное происхождение - от
> глагола прягти, пряжити ‘жарить,
> печь’, который мы находим во многих
> славянских языках, но только в
> украинском он имеет также значение
> ‘топить молоко’ (УРС, с.675).
>
> С точки
> зрения другого учёного, этимология
> названия этого продук­та связана с
> особенностями его приготовления: в
> результате долгого ки­пячения молока
> образуются «наслоения рядов молочных
> сгустков» (Лутовинова, с.167). Как
> видно, исследователь устанавливает
> семантиче­скую связь анализируемой
> единицы с лексемой ряд, однако в
> «Словооб­разовательном словаре»
> А.Н.Тихонова она стоит особняком, не
> попадая ни в одно словообразовательное
> гнездо (2; 881).
>
> Можно также
> предположить, что ряженка связана с
> глаголом ря­дить, ряживать, одно из
> значений которого - ‘готовить,
> припасать и делать’ (Д 4; 125); ср. с
> бытующими в воронежских говорах
> названиями пирог ряженый ‘пирог с
> начинкой’ и ряженец ‘большой пирог’.
>
> Этимология слова может быть также
> раскрыта с помощью сопоставления с
> лексемой редкий, которая в словаре
> В.И.Даля имеет значение ‘жидкий’ и
> соотносится со словом ряжъ.

Comment: Мне думается, что РЯЖЕНКА и ВАРЕНЕЦ скорее связаны с именами давнишних  молочников, внедривших эти напитки. РЯЖЕНКА это имя типа европейского РУЗИНА (женск.). ВАРЕНЕЦ тоже просматривается, например, в "бароне Врангеле" (В-Р-Н + гель). Ранее  я уже писал о присутствии имени создателя  в названии пищевого продукта - см. мой Ответ в "Почему голубцы ?".

Answer (score 3):

Неряха. "Не"- выступает в этом слове в качестве простого отрицания. Поэтому в качестве утверждения выступает слово "ряха". Это слово еще можно встретить в народных говорах русского языка - "ряха", "ряжоха". Что означает - аккуратист, чистюля. То есть человек, которая любит и в одежде, и делах порядок(ряд, лад, порядок), от этих слов произведены такие слова, как наряд, наряжать, обрядить, суженый-ряженый и т.п. Наряд - это своего рода форма, где все к месту.

И "ряженка" тут тоже в тему. Её ведь тоже наряжают, "рядят" в печи, в отличие от простоквашеного молока(без закваски и наряда печным жаром).